# How to add a new label to a multi-label dataset (like Open Images)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training, multilabel-classification

Given N classes in a multi-label dataset and a trained classifier C, how would we add a new class N+1 to the dataset, and fine-tune the trained classifier C such that it now predicts N+1 labels? (lets call this fine-tuned N+1 class classifier C'). Let's use Open Images as an example, which has 9,000,000 images in the dataset.

The issue is with the data and it being a multi-label dataset. Say we have 5000 images from the N+1 class.

The first issue is that there may be other objects from any of the N classes in the images besides class N+1 (these images are taken from the web). So we run the trained classifier C on the 5000 images and have machine annotations for the other N classes in the 5000 images. We then use turkers to verify all the labels.

Now the second (unsolved) issue is, how to find instances of the N+1 class in the original 9,000,000 training set? If we don't find these 'false negatives' in the original training set, fine-tuning could have unexpected results.